# Video not showing in iPhone Simulator (but I can hear audio from the video)

Tags: iphone, video, uitabbarcontroller, ios-simulator, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am new to xcode, interface builder, and the iphone simulator. I am trying to play a movie/video in xcode on the click of a button (which is very straightforward). I am using xcode 3.2.4 and iphone simulator 4.1.

When I launch the iPhone simulator and click the button to launch the video, the audio plays, but the video is hidden. It's as if the video is behind the tab bar (this is part of a tab bar application). I am not sure how to make the video play in front.

Here's the code:

```
    -(IBAction)launchVideo2:(id)sender{

 NSString *movieFile;
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

 movieFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
     pathForResource:@"IGDIs_Video_Picture_Naming_iPhone" ofType:@"mp4"];
 moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
       initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: movieFile]];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(playMediaFinished:)
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
              object:moviePlayer];
 moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
 [moviePlayer play];
}

-(void)playMediaFinished:(NSNotification*)theNotification
{
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[theNotification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
              object:moviePlayer];

    [moviePlayer release];
}
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2):

should be using the [MPMoviePlayerViewcontroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerViewController)

see apple documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

Comment: i am not the greatest at reading/understanding the documentation yet... do you have an example of code that uses the MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Comment: try the stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077096/how-can-i-play-a-movie-locally-with-the-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller

Comment: i copied the code exactly from the example you provided above and added the suggested code:

Comment: [moviePlayerViewController play];
[window addSubview:MPMoviePlayerViewController.view];

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to send both comments. I copied the code from the example and added this code:
 
[moviePlayerViewController play]; 
[window addSubview:MPMoviePlayerViewController.view];    

but I get two errors: 
1st error - "'window' undeclared." 
2nd error - "MPMoviePlayerViewController may not respond to '-play'"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have added the movie view to your main view. You'll need to add something like:

```
    ...
    [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:[self view] bounds]];
    [[self view] addSubview:[moviePlayer view]]; 
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

before playing it. I'm assuming that the a launchVideo2 method is in a UIViewController that owns the main view. You might have to change `[self view]` to suit your code to correspond to the view where you want the movie to play.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, video won't display in the sim. However, audio will. (Which is an improvement, since previously neither would play.)

Try running the app on the device. If the video doesn't display there, post here and we'll work through the issue.

Comment: Looks like you're missing     [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];  (see Aaron Saunders comment)

Answer (score 0):

You have a probably unrelated memory issue there:

- In your first method, you don't release the player, which is a local variable.
- In your second method, you release the player, that you don't own.

Proper memory management (ie best practice), you would do this with an ivar.