# How can I play a movie locally with the MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an mp4 file called lebron.mp4 in my Resources folder:

```
-(IBAction)videoButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                     pathForResource:@"lebron" 
                     ofType:@"mp4"];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController* moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    moviePlayerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];

    [moviePlayerViewController release];    
}
```

Displays the movie player, but the movie doesn't play. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to display it like this :

```
[moviePlayerViewController play];
[window addSubview: MPMoviePlayerViewController.view];
```

?